# Spyder 3.7 - How to store value in a variable from a function

Tags: python, variables, spyder, explorer

I realize this is probably really simple, I do it in Matlab all the time. Right now, all I want to do is use a button in tkinter to open a file dialog, choose a file, and store the pathname in a variable.

```
class Functions:
    def FileDialog(Pathname):
        Pathname = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

Funks = Functions()
Btn1 = tkinter.Button(MainWindow, text = "Browse", command = Funks.FileDialog)
```

After the function is done, where does "Pathname" go? How can I view it in the variables explorer?

Update: I've structured the code differently now and here it is in its entirety

```
##########################################
import tkinter as tk                     #
from tkinter import Frame                #
import tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog#
##########################################

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.MainWindow()

    def MainWindow(self):
        self.master.title("The SHIFT Show"); self.pack() 
        Btn1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Browse", command = self.FileDialog)
        Btn1.place(x = 0, y = 0); Btn1.pack()
        Btn2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Close Window", command = self.Exit) 
        Btn2.place(x = 0, y = 0); Btn2.pack()
        Btn3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Pathname?", command = self.PathTest)
        Btn3.place(x = 0, y = 0); Btn3.pack()

    def FileDialog(self):
        Pathname = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        return Pathname

    def Exit(self):
        exit() #DOESNT WORK

    def PathTest(self,Pathname):
        print(Pathname)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.geometry("500x500+2500+1100")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What IDE (interactive development environment) are you using?  We don't know what "the variables explorer" is, since that's not a Python component.

Comment: _After the function is done, where does "Pathname" go?_ What do you mean where does it go? As an aside, I'm guessing that the class you show here is just an example?

Comment: I think I see it now: you're assigning the method FileDialog as the "click-on" functionality for a GUI button, and you want to know how to capture the user-entered path from the text box.  Is that correct?

Comment: I'm using Spyder 4.0.1. I want to have a file dialog open and the user selects a file, then that file path is stored for later use. I actually just now got it to do what I wanted. I used global variable `def FileDialog(self):
        global Pathname;
        folderpath = tkFileDialog.askdirectory();
        Pathname = folderpath        
    ` 
now I can pass `Pathname` to other functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to do what I wanted. yay.

```
##########################################
import tkinter as tk                     #
from tkinter import Frame                #
import tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog#
##########################################

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.MainWindow()

    def MainWindow(self):
        self.master.title("The SHIFT Show"); self.pack() 
        # BUTTONS
        ## File dialog button
        Btn1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Browse", command = self.FileDialog)
        Btn1.place(x = 0, y = 0); Btn1.pack()
        ## Close window button
        Btn2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Close Window", command = self.Exit) 
        Btn2.place(x = 0, y = 0); Btn2.pack()
        ## Test button for....things
        Btn3 = tk.Button(self, text = "Pathname?", command = self.PathTest)
        Btn3.place(x = 0, y = 0); Btn3.pack()

    def FileDialog(self):
        global Pathname
        folderpath = tkFileDialog.askdirectory()
        Pathname = folderpath        

    def Exit(self):
        exit() # STILL DOESNT WORK

    def PathTest(self):
        print(Pathname) # Outputs the folder path to the console (so I know it's there)

root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.geometry("500x500+2500+1100")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Functions` class is not working properly because you have not set up its methods to work as methods. A normal method needs to expect the instance of the class to be passed in as the first argument (by convention this argument is named `self`, though that's not strictly required).

After you have a `self` argument, you can create attributes on it to store data that gets passed into your methods. This is probably what you're looking for here.

Try this:

```
class Functions:
    def file_dialog(self):
        self.pathname = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

Now if you create an instance named `funks` and pass `funks.file_dialog` as a callback to your button, it will save the filename selected by the user as `funks.pathname`. Note that I've renamed several of your function and variable names a bit to map better to Python typical style, where `CapitalizedNames` are only used for classes and most other variables (and functions) are given `lower_case_names_with_underscores`.

Note that you might want to structure your code differently and not name your class `Functions`, as a class's purpose should really be to keep a bunch of *data* together (with related methods). Classes are not usually just used as a namespace to put unrelated functions in. If you just need a namespace, a module is the obvious choice. I think a class *does* make sense in the situation you're asking about here, but you should name the class with its data in mind! If you deal with unrelated data in different parts of the code, that suggests you probably want different classes for those parts.

Comment: I've noticed that the structure isn't great, and I've gone with defining everything separately, which I think will work better in the long run. This code has a LONG way to go. I'm basically translating from Matlab to Python and I'm experiencing quite a few growing pains thus far.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you don't.  `Pathname` is a local variable.  By definition, it does not exist once you exit the function.  The call space is popped off the run-time stack, the memory is released and reclaimed, and none of that information is available any more.

If you want to work with that value at all, you need to somehow transfer it outside that function.  Typical methods include:

- print it out (useful for humans; not for the rest of your code)
- `return` it at the end of the function
- pass in a mutable argument; store Pathname in the corresponding parameter

This last one would require being able to change the signature (call profile) of `FileDialog`, and being able to push a second argument to it.

Comment: I've tried ```return```, but I can't see where this goes. How do I call```Pathname```for later use?

Comment: You don't: `Pathname` is a string, not a function; you cannot "call" it.
Obviously, I'm not entirely clear on what you want to do -- in part, because you failed to update your question with the code including `return`.

Comment: ok, sure. I don't want to "call" it. I would like to guess use it later on in the script for file handling. When I am in debug mode I can see it show up in the variable explorer however Spyder 4.0.1 seems a little buggy when I tell it to continue running the script after the breakpoint i set. I can't tell if it indeed moved onto the rest of the script as the little blue arrow stays on the breakpoint line.